# WorksheetFunction SumProduct Error 1004 in nested loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, worksheet-function, with-statement

I'm running into a '1004' error when trying to call `WorksheetFunction.SumProduct` within a loop.

What I am trying to achieve: Filtering for two variables succesively, and then creating ranges of the visible cells only to calculate a volume-weighted average using the sumproduct function.

Any help is much appreciated!

Please find my code below:

```
With wsS
     .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("B1:U" & lRow)
                For i = 0 To uBS - 1 'Step -1
                    '.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=sArray(i) ', Operator:=xlFilterValues
                    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=result(i)
                        For j = 0 To uBD - 1
                            .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=result2(j)
                            endrowTs = Worksheets(10).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).End(xlUp).Row
                                If Not endrowTs < 2 Then
                                    With Worksheets(10).Range("M2:M" & endrowTs)
                                    Set r1 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                                    End With
                                    With Worksheets(10).Range("M2:M" & endrowTs)
                                    Set r2 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                                    End With
                                    VolG = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(r1, r2)
                                Else
                                End If
                            
                        Next j
                Next i
        End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Already tried a lot but nothing helped so far, e.g.

`VolG = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(.Range("L2:L" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Range("M2:M" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))`

Comment: 1. are you sure there are visible cells? 2. r1 and r2 are going to be disjointed ranges and as such SUMPRODUCT will fail. You will need to loop the areas and sum the results each loop.

Comment: personally I would loop the rows testing if the row is visible and if so do the math.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for your quick reply! I tested the code with Worksheetfunction.Sum, that works without a problem. There definitely are visible cells. Also tested the code on the dataset without filtering/looping. Doing this, sumproduct works fine. Therefore I thought it must be a wrong syntax I am using?

Comment: No, SUMPRODUCT does not work with disjointed ranges and the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will return such.

Comment: Understood. Disjointed range e.g. is when rows 2,5,6 and 8 have data? I was hoping when creating a new range, r1, this would be jointed since copying it to a new sheet looks fine. But thanks. I guess SUMPRODUCT on a filtered range is hence not possible at all?

How would you loop through the rows and wouldn't this not take much longer?

Comment: Time depends on how many rows.  It is not ideal, but looping the areas would probably be on slightly quicker.  You could always copy the data to a new worksheet range then use that new range in sumproduct then delete the new range.  That may be a little quicker.

Comment: I was hoping that I could avoid that extra step copying it to a new worksheet but learning about the diskointed ranges it might be the best option. Thanks a lot!

One more thing? Would it be possible to copy that range to the same worksheet leaving enough space to my data, e.g. using LASTROW + (large) X ?

Comment: You can always use the same sheet.

Comment: `With .Range("B1:U" & lRow)` in your current code this is not scoped to `wsS`

Answer (score 0):

On the sheet below you can see illustration how we can use `SUMPRODUCT` function on a filtered range. You can use either formulas or VBA code. Possible versions of formulas:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$C$9,$D$3:$D$9,SUBTOTAL(3,INDIRECT("B"&ROW($B$3:$B$9))))
=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$C$9,$D$3:$D$9,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($B$3,ROW($B$3:$B$9)-ROW($B$3),0)))
```

3 versions of VBA code (all of them work, however I didn't compare their speed for bigger ranges).

```
Sub SumProductWithFilter1()
       Dim Subtot As Double, V As Variant, r As Long
       With WorksheetFunction
              V = Range("B3:B9").Value
              For r = 1 To UBound(V)
                      V(r, 1) = .Subtotal(3, Range("B3:B9")(r))
              Next r
              Subtot = .SumProduct(Range("C3:C9").Value, _
                       Range("D3:D9").Value, V)
       End With
       If IsNumeric(Subtot) Then MsgBox Subtot
End Sub

Sub SumProductWithFilter2()
       Dim Subtot As Double, V As Variant, c As Long
        V = Range("B3:B9").Value
              For c = 1 To UBound(V)
                      V(c, 1) = 1 + CLng(Range("B3:B9")(c).Rows.Hidden)
              Next c
       With WorksheetFunction
              Subtot = .SumProduct(Range("C3:C9").Value, _
                       Range("D3:D9").Value, V)
       End With
       If IsNumeric(Subtot) Then MsgBox Subtot
End Sub

Sub SumProductWithFilter3()
       Dim Subtot
       Subtot = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(C3:C9,D3:D9,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B3,ROW(B3:B9)-ROW(B3),0)))")
       If IsNumeric(Subtot) Then MsgBox Subtot
End Sub
```

[image: SumProduct]